# Where can I get Super-sized Dung?

Tags: monster-hunter-3-ultimate

To upgrade my farm I need 300p, two Dung, and one Super-sized Dung.

I have the points, and the regular dung is readily available, but where can I find the big stuff?

Comment: I have to puke. Bai.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Super-sized Dung comes from very large Aptonoths during the free hunting.  This is the time when you leave Moga Village by the Farm or the bridge out of town.

The trick is to check the Moga Forecast.  What you're specifically looking for is "Herbivores breeding".  On those days, when you go to Area 2, you'll find at least one giant Aptonoth.  Kill it, and when you report your hunt to Juni- I mean, the Chief's son, you'll get a Super-sized Dung.  You can leave the area, and come back, and there should be another giant Aptonoth waiting for you.  Alternatively, kill all Aptonoths, and wait.  More will come running in from Area 1, and the first will be a giant one.  Kill, rinse, and repeat.

Answer (score 2):

Free hunt! You have to kill the really big aptanoth in the forest during the herbivore breeding time.

Answer (score 2):

I got mine from killing the Great Jaggi and turning in the report for him. Got a lot in a matter of fact. I was searching for a answer and heard monster report. Ran to check and saw the "Great Jaggi" had got me a .. excuse the pun, crapload of supersized dung!